# Creating a public dataset (or: split storage costs and compute costs across two projects)

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use BigQuery to host datasets that others can query without incurring processing charges against my project. I understand that when I upload a dataset to a project, the storage costs are associated with the project. I want others to be able to discover my dataset, access it via **their** project/account (preferably without my intervention), and run as many queries on it as they choose to pay for. So, storage costs would go to me, but compute costs would go to those who run the queries.

Is there a way to do this in BigQuery? I asked this via the Google Cloud enterprise sales [web form](https://cloud.google.com/contact) but did not get a response.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely! You can certainly make a dataset public to be queried from other projects, or even share your dataset only with a specific domain, group or user.

In this model, users would be charged for queries to their own Project IDs, while your project covers the storage costs of the datasets. Note that if the users running queries in a different project want to store their resulting tables from their query results, they would of course pay for this storage themselves.

BigQuery currently doesn't provide a mechanism for public dataset discovery. You would have to share the details of your project's public dataset(s) yourself. The [GitHub Archive](http://www.githubarchive.org/) project has a good example of this.

Comment: This sounds great, but I don't see how to make a dataset public. When I try to share a dataset, I only see options for Project Readers/Writers/Owners, and individual email addresses.

Comment: In the web UI, on the share dataset modal popup, look for the icon under "Add people:" - click on it, and you should see the option to share with "All Authenticated Users."

Comment: Ah, I see that now. I have created a brand new project with a single dataset containing a single table with a handful of rows, and I have enabled View privileges for the dataset with All Authenticated Users. When others try to access it, they are able to see the project but not the table. For example, are you able to access this dataset/table ( siebert.org:publictest:publicdataset.publictable ) ? The project id is 12126759680. If so, please tell me how.

Comment: SELECT TOP(repository_name, 5) as repo, COUNT(*) as count FROM [siebert.org:publictest:publicdataset.publictable]; gives me 
repo count  = 
origin-server 3  
rails 2  
bootcamp 2  
Specs 2  
zabbix-benchmark 1

Comment: Excellent, that's the syntax I was looking for.

Comment: Can I share a dataset with another project without making it public?

Comment: You can share a BQ dataset with other (Google) emails, group emails, or by domain, or with owners, editors and readers of the Project.

Comment: I have created a separate question specifically about 'a mechanism for public dataset discovery' here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032017/how-to-search-for-public-datasets-on-bigquery, along with a votable Idea on Google Uservocie (link in question post).