# Google BigQuery access public dataset through API

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I have shared a dataset to All Authenticated Users here:

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/master-smithy-633:nyc_taxi.total_amount_month

I can access it from a different account through Web UI. But when I run Javascript OAuth to access the dataset, I get the following error:

```
Object {code: 403, message: "Access Denied: Job master-smithy-633:job_PcyI97Mklw8mbJQUWGhgCxRRKTQ: RUN_QUERY_JOB", data: Array[1], error: Object}
```

Here's the code that access the dataset. You can clone it to see the error:

https://vida.io/documents/icwvp4qcCbEkYW2ve

How do I enable querying of the above shared dataset in different Google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't that you don't have access to the data, the issue is that user making the request doesn't have access to run the query job in the project.

For billing and accounting purposes, all jobs (including queries) must be attributed to a Cloud project. The project permissions set who is allowed to run jobs in that project (since the project is responsible for billing). This is true even when you don't have billing enabled, since there is a quota for unbilled query usage that gets charged to the project.

So you tried to run a job in the project master-smithy-c33, which the user making the request didn't have rights to. You can set project rights via the google developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/). Or you can run in a different project that you have rights to run jobs in.

Comment: I assume you're talking about this permission: http://imgur.com/PZ1KN9F. I tried to set it but it doesn't save. Also, my permissions are set to "Can edit" for all credentials. It should include "Can view" as well?

Comment: What user are you running OAuth for? Is it the user accessing the website? Is it the service account?

Comment: Jordan, I'm not sure I understand your questions. I'm using OAuth in my Javascript code. I want to be able to show other people the visualization so they can view it. So I share to All Authenticated User. When another user hits the page, Javascript call to query returns 403 error. This user is logged into Google under a different account.

Comment: The user that is making the requests must be a member of the project you are running the job in. In this case, they would either need their own project or be a member of master-smithy-c33.

Comment: Hi Jordan, I can share data access to a particular email address. But I'm looking for a way to share it to public. Is this possible? This thread suggests to use "All Authenticated Users". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967967/creating-a-public-dataset-or-split-storage-costs-and-compute-costs-across-two

Comment: As I mentioned, the issue isn't sharing the data, it is granting the rights to be able to run query jobs. Any bigquery user can read that table (I can run queries against it, for example), but they cannot run queries in your project (which is good, otherwise you'd be billed for it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57779/discussion-between-phuoc-do-and-jordan-tigani).